# Using on or in for geometric points, planes, and coordinate systems

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

When to use "on" and "in" prepositions in math:

- > Point on/in the plane
- > Point on/in the cartesian coordinate system

Comment: WRT points and planes, they are interchangeable.  WRT coordinate systems, use "in" because the coordinate system does not have an identifiable surface on which a point could exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***ON***

We can describe features **on** surfaces or boundaries.  Those surfaces can be of any dimension.  (A point ON a line, a point ON a circle, a point ON "the plane," a point ON the surface of a cylinder, a point ON the surface of a klein bottle.)

***INSIDE***

For closed surfaces, we can refer to points that are on one side of the surface or the other (within boundaries).  (A point INSIDE a circle, a point INSIDE  a cylinder.  A point WITHIN/INSIDE the boundaries of a region)

***IN***

When we refers to systems or spaces we use **in**.  (A point IN 3-space.  A point IN a coordinate system.  A vector IN Hilbert Space)